# How to use neo4j presented on the web?

Tags: java, neo4j

I use neo4j 2.2.4.

Now,I want to use neo4j presented on the web,but I don't know how to do!

Please help me ,and give me some teaching article.

Thanks.

Comment: please forgive my sarcasm, but the best teaching article for this kind of question is http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Sorry,my english is very bed,and I really don't know to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the Neo4j Example Project which shows how to use a simple one-page web-"app" with a backend in any language we have a driver for running with a Neo4j Server:

http://neo4j.com/developer/example-project/

You see it running live here: http://my-neo4j-movies-app.herokuapp.com

Comment: Thank your answer,may I use JSP for Neo4j on web application?